# Dynamics CRM: Retrieving RelatedEntities of the entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am trying to retrieve RelatedEntities collection of the existing entity but every time it's returning null value. Not sure what I am missing here. Any help or any other workaround to retrieve RelatedEntities is much appreciated. Here is my code snippet:

```csharp
Entity existingAppointment = _service.Retrieve("appointment", id, new ColumnSet(true));
Console.WriteLine(existingAppointment.RelatedEntities.Count);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish that you have use RollupRequest, see more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.rolluprequest.aspx).